# Empty http response body

Tags: c#, sockets, http, network-programming, httpresponse

I am trying to make HTTP request/response using sockets in C#. GET request appears below.

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.AppendFormat("GET http://{0}/ HTTP/1.1\r\n", hostname);
 sb.AppendFormat("Host: {0}\r\n", hostname);
 sb.Append("Connection: keep-alive\r\n");
 sb.Append(@"Accept:text/html,*/*");
 sb.Append("\r\n\r\n");
```

where *hostname* is something like 'mit.edu' or 'facebook.com' or 'google.com' or anything else. For some strange reason I have just a status-line (with 200 status code) and headers as http response. But there is no message body in the response: [attached srceenshot of my console app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3PED.png)

Here is a method that perform all manipulations with socket and make http request:

```
public static void DoHttpGetRequest(String hostname, Int16 port = 80) {
      IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);
      IPAddress ipAdress = ipHostEntry.AddressList[0];
      IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAdress, port);

      Socket socket = new Socket(ipAdress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

      socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);

      String request = CreateRequest(hostname);

      Byte[] byteRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
      Byte[] byteResponse = new Byte[1000];

      int bytesSent = socket.Send(byteRequest);
      int bytesReceive = socket.Receive(byteResponse);

      Console.WriteLine(request);
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteResponse, 0, bytesReceive));

      socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
      socket.Close();
}
```

My first thought was that the socket hadn't received the whole response from the server. In this case I do still not know how to solve the problem.

So what is going on? Where is the mistake?

Comment: Not sure what kind of service you are calling here but if it is giving you http code 200 which means OK then it must have done something. Probably a problem at the server side?

Do you own the service? Any chance to look @ the log or trace the code from there?

Comment: @Tendious, thanx for your answer. The servise isn't mine. I've run the code a lot of times for different services. There are senate.gov, ex.ua, mit.edu, google.com, fs.to and other and other among them. All that requests got their responses with code 200OK or 302Found or 301 and without message body. So I am not sure that it is about a problem at the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't expect to get the full response inside a single receive. What you do is to receive data until you have the full response header (this could take several receive calls too), then parse the header to find out how long the response is and then read the necessary data of the response which also can need multiple receive calls. And since you are doing a HTTP/1.1 request you also have to deal with chunked responses.

I recommend to better use a HTTP library to handle all the problems. If you insist on doing it all by your own read [the specification of HTTP](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) and implemented accordingly. 
It also helps to look around at [stackoverflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+http+socket+only&oq=stackoverflow+http+socket+only) for similar requests because this problem you have is very typical for someone trying to implement HTTP first time, without understanding enough on how sockets, TCP and HTTP work.

Comment: RFC 2616 is deprecated ("*Obsoleted by: 7230, 7231, 7232, 7233, 7234, 7235*"). For the successors please read here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/ and here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616

Comment: @alk: I know, but it makes easier to point to a single RFC than to several. And the differences in the specification between these RFC are minor and any browser differs way more from the specification than the old and the new specification.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep the socket open for a longer time. Insert a

```
Thread.Wait(5000);
```

may help. Then you can do a second socket.Receive as Steffen proposed. Maybe you can try the following (wait until the server closed the connection):

```
while (socket.Connected) do
{
    int bytesReceive = socket.Receive(byteResponse);
}
```

But I didn't test this. It's easier to use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

Everything I need to do is to receive data with multiple receive calls until all response information received.

```
do
{                
     bytesReceive = socket.Receive(byteResponse, byteResponse.Length, 0);
     response += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteResponse, 0, bytesReceive);
}
while (bytesReceive > 0);
```

Thanx everybody for your help!